# Clear terminal every second but leave minutes

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, clock

I have a seconds and minute counter, very similar to my timer. However, I cannot get the number of minutes to stay on screen.

```
int main()
{
    int spam = 0;
    int minute = 0;

    while (spam != -1)
    {
        spam++;
        std::cout << spam << " seconds" << std::endl;
        Sleep(200);
        system("CLS");
        //I still want the system to clear the seconds
        if ((spam % 60) == 0)
        {
            minute++;
            std::cout << minute << " minutes" << std::endl;
        }
        //but not the minutes
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to reprint the minutes after every clear screen. Currently you only print them every `spam%60==0`

Comment: That's what I'm stuck on. Do you happen to know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system("CLS")` will clear the screen, which you do each iteration of the `while` loop, whereas you only print the `minute` every *minute or so*.

You need to print the minute every iteration:

```
while (spam != -1)
{
    spam++;
    if (minute)
        std::cout << minute << " minutes" << std::endl;
    std::cout << spam << " seconds" << std::endl;
    Sleep(200);
    system("CLS");
    if ((spam % 60) == 0)
    {
        minute++;
    }
}
```

Here I assume you only want to print the minute if it's not zero, hence `if (minute)`.

FWIW: you probably want to reset `spam` to `0` when you update `minute`, but that depends on what you're doing. Perhaps you simply wish to display the number of *seconds* elapsed in total.

Comment: Thank you so much!!